# Creating multiple stored procedures from SQL executed by powershell issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Ok, so I've got a bit of a SQL and Powershell problem. There are 2 SQL scripts, one to setup 4 different global stored procedures. Another to execute them and manipulate data before returning it to PS to be placed in a CSV file. The reason I'm not putting them into a single file is for readability. The procs are enclosing huge chunks of sql and I cannot create permanent procs in our production environment.

The problem I'm running into is the script runs fine in SQL Mgmt Studio but when ran by PS, I get several errors around the 'go's in the script.

I'm pretty sure this is a problem with the format that PS and the .NET classes expect when executing and returning data sets but...I'm at a loss.

I'm running SQL Server 2005 btw.

Any ideas or similar experiences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What errors do you get?  How are you executing each file?  GO is a batch separator understood only by certain tools (e.g. Management Studio); PowerShell doesn't know what GO means.  Have you tried executing the separate CREATE PROCEDURE scripts without issuing a GO command between them?  If they are separate commands this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I have tried removing the go statements but get 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'procedure'. I know this is something trivial but I cant think of what to save my life.

Comment: And at that point what exactly is PowerShell sending to SQL Server?  Sounds like it's not a complete CREATE PROCEDURE script.  Maybe you should use some kind of tool to put these files together before PowerShell runs them, because I'm not sure you can control or grasp exactly what PowerShell is doing (or you're just not able to communicate that to us effectively).

Answer (score 2):

"GO" is a delimiter used by SQL Management Studio.  It is not a valid SQL keyword.  You can configure SQL Management Studio and change "GO" to "ENGAGE" if you wanted to.

Just remove "GO" from the scripts.